# User account that is not allowed to edit one file on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, root, user

I wanted to ask if it is possible to create a user account on Ubuntu so that it had all powers and rights of root account except it would be impossible to edit a certain file.

What I intend to do is to edit **host** file in order to block access of certain websites, and then create a user account which would be the same as root account except it would be not able to edit **host** file. Maybe there is an easier way to block an access of certain sites forever?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) will allow you to assign a role or to use MLS to prevent the user acting as root from reading the file.